# Name of a custom fuction in Keras model R

Tags: r, keras

I have created a custom loss function:

```
RMSE= function(y_true,y_pred){
 k_sqrt(k_mean(k_square(y_pred-y_true)))
}
```

And it works fine but when I run:

```
model$loss
```

Get:

```
<function make_python_function.<locals>.python_function at 0x0000026A51F5c80>
```

Instead of the name of the loss function, like when I used for example 'mse'

```
model$loss
"mse"
```

What should I add to my custom function to be able to get the name?