# How to load a Keras model with a custom loss function?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I have created the following custom loss function:

```r
RMSE = function(y_true,y_pred) {
         k_sqrt(k_mean(k_square(y_pred - y_true))) 
    }
```

And it works fine when I saved the model. However, when I loaded the model back using:

```r
load_model_hdf5(filepath= "modelpath")
```

**I get the following error:**

```r
#Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords):
#      valueError: Unknown loss function:RMSE
```

Maybe this question has something in common with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599127/name-of-a-custom-fuction-in-keras-model-r) I made before. What should I do to stop getting this error?

Comment: Tryusing load_model_hdf5(filepath= "modelpath", compile=False). What do you get? Could you also include the rest of your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a *custom* loss function in your model, the loss function would not be saved when persisting the model on disk and instead only its name would be included in the model file. Then, when you want to load back the model at a later time, you need to inform the model of the corresponding loss function for the stored name. To provide that mapping, you can use `custom_objects` argument of `load_model_hdf5` function:

```
load_model_hdf5(filepath = "modelpath", custom_objects = list(RMSE = RMSE))
```

Alternatively, after training is finished, if you just want to use the model for prediction you can just pass `compile = False` argument to `load_model_hdf5` function (hence, the loss function would not be needed and loaded):

```
load_model_hdf5(filepath = "modelpath", compile = False)
```